# What is wrong with my regex concatenation?

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio, concatenation

I am perplexed as to why this line is my code is not doing anything to the inputed string.

```
result = Regex.Replace(astring, @"\b"+Regex.Escape(words[i])+@"\b", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

So basically I have a method that takes in a string and will replace a word in the string with an empty string if it is in the prohibited words array. I've also tried.

```
result = Regex.Replace(astring, @"\b"+words[i]+@"\b", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Nothing is wrong with my array or anything else because without using regex it will replace substrings, but i need it to match and replace whole words so thats why I am using regex.

Please help!

Comment: So variable result will have the Replaced value. (Assuming Regex worked) -- What are you expecting? Can you add sample Input string and few Escape Words -- so that we can verify your regex.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to see what you are doing here. however

```
var astring = "bob dog cat brown cow";
var list = new List<string>{"dog", "brown"};
var escapedList = list.Select(word => Regex.Escape(word)).ToList();

// i guess this is what you are trying to do
foreach (var word in escapedList)
{
    var result = Regex.Replace(astring, @"\b" + Regex.Escape(word) + @"\b", "xxx", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

Console.WriteLine();

// i'm guessing this is more what you want
var result2 = Regex.Replace(astring,  $@"\b{string.Join(@"\b|\b", escapedList)}\b", "xxx", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Console.WriteLine(result2);
```

**Outputs**

```
bob xxx cat brown cow
bob dog cat xxx cow

bob xxx cat xxx cow
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lB2SrU)

Answer (score 0):

Using an index `i` inside `words[i]` suggests that you are calling this in a loop. However, in this case you keep the result of only the last replacement, because you pass the original string `astring` to each call. Therefore, only the replacement of the last `word[i]` would "stick", while all other replacements would get discarded.

You can fix this by assigning `result = astring`, and then calling your regex as follows:

```
result = Regex.Replace(
    result
,   @"\b"+Regex.Escape(words[i])+@"\b"
,   ""
,   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

However, this is suboptimal: you would be better off constructing a single regex, and performing all substitutions in a single go:

```
var allWords = @"\b"
+   string.Join("|", words.Select(w => Regex.Escape(w)))
+   @"\b";
result = Regex.Replace(astring, allWords, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```